# Возможность поменять расположение миниатюр панели задач

Tags: windows-7

Вопрос относится к интерфейсу управления запущенными программами в ОС Windows7 и старше.
Если запустить несколько приложений одного типа, они сворачиваются в стопку в панели задач. При нажатии на эту панель задач появляются миниатюры запущенный приложений. Существует ли какая-либо возможность (кроме перезапуска приложений в нужной последовательности) поменять местами миниатюры?

Например сделать так, чтобы документ2 был слева[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть программа "7 Taskbar Tweaker" http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker.

В ней есть такая возможность:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может вы владеете информацией, в какой настройке это хранится? Может быть параметр в реестре или конфигурационный файл? Т.к. если твикер это настраивает, то можно настроить и без твикера

Comment: Так как после выгрузки твикера эта возможность пропадает, то наверняка подобное перемещение делает возможным сам твикер.

Comment: Да, уже посмотрел у них на сайте:  There are no registry keys for the options it provides. The tweaker does that by injecting a DLL to explorer, hooking/subclassing/some other methods of the dark side.